# How can i output the result of "memusage" to a text?

Tags: linux, memory

When i execute a command `memusage` to check the memory of my program, the result is as follows. I want to output the result in the red circle to a text. How should i do?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep`:

```
memusage <your_options> |& grep -E -o 'heap peak: [0-9]+'
```

or `sed`:

```
memusage <your_options> |& sed -E -n 's/.*(heap peak: [0-9]+).*/\1/p'
```

or even `awk`, but I don't have an immediate answer for that.

Comment: But this command output to which document?@Kusalananda

Comment: @wwb1 The terminal.

Comment: `|&` is a bashism

Comment: i want to know what is the “[0-9]+"mean? if the number behind the "heap peak:" more than 9 digits, it is still work correctly?@dr_

Comment: @wwb It's a regex that matches numbers with 1 or more digits.  So the answer to your second question is "yes".